# Why is this calculation producing a wrong result?

Tags: pine-script

Please see the code below:

```
var test1=0.0
test1 := (100+((80/100)*6))
```

The answer is 104.8 according to Excel, however Pine is telling me the answer is 100.  Why is this?
I have tried some other calculations e.g. test1 `:= (100+1) + (100+2), whic`h produces the correct result i.e. 203 in this case.

I have read through the documentation here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html and I have also Googled it, but still I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this problem occurs, it could be a bug. As you can see its not a rounding problem, it rather seems that here pinescript skip the calculations involving both division and multiplication.

A solution is to treat one of the dividend/divisor or factor in a calculation producing a decimal number as a double instead of an integer, this can be done using a trailing dot:

```
var test1=0.0
test1 := 100 + 80./100*6
```

This will produce the expected result.

Comment: Thanks.  That does appear to work.  When do you use := over =.  Is it used when reassigning?

Comment: Yes, `:=` is used for reassignment, it is mostly used when we want to use recursion.

Comment: Before I upvote - what does the full stop after 80 do? It seems to be critical here.

Comment: Do you mean trailing dot? Adding a dot after an integer will treat it as a double.